# if test in javascript for boolean value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a boolean variable which passes the if test even if its value is false.

Here is the code:

```
var go = (4 > 8);
if(go) {
    //do something
}
```

The `//do something` is always executing even if the value of go is `false`. I tested `if(go == true)` and `if(go === true)` as well but in all these cases it passes the test and `//do something` gets executed.

What am I doing wrong here?

The code above is in an `else if` block but that should not matter.

Could someone help me understand what am I doing wrong here? I've gone nuts trying to figure out why is it happening.

Comment: Are you cached with older code? Clear it and see if it magically works.

Comment: Its working fine for me..once check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3BTw4/2/

Comment: @epascarello: Man you're a life saver. I just cleaned the cache and it worked :).

Comment: @zzzzBov: I am not sure why but refreshing the page did not work.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with the code

just try this

say you web url is http://localtest/test.php

try appending http://localtest/test.php?test=something

this may load your js again and not pick up the cached version 
Edit: you are better off clearing your browser cache

Comment: Does a refresh doesn't load the javascript again? I tried that like a gazillion times but all the times the test passed.

Comment: Offcourse that was part of a solution. Generally I would clear my cache using browser options. but thats the simplest this you could have tried. thanks for -1.